# Вопрос про proxy сервер

Tags: java

Изучения для решил подобие firewall'а написать. Но данные приходят только в консольку idea. Как мне направить их еще и в броузер?

```
public class Proxy extends Thread {
    Socket s;
    InputStream is;
    OutputStream os;

    public Proxy(Socket s){
        this.s = s;
        setDaemon(true);
        setPriority(NORM_PRIORITY);
        start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try
        {
            ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(3128, 0, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));

            System.out.println("proxy is started");


            while(true)
            {
                try {
                    new Proxy(s.accept());
                } 
                catch(Exception ex) {}
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {System.out.println("main init error: "+e);} 
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            is = s.getInputStream();
            os = s.getOutputStream();


            byte buf[] = new byte[64*1024];
            int r = is.read(buf);

            String header = new String(buf, 0, r);
            System.out.println(header);
            s.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e){

                try
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Error");
                    s.close();
                }
                catch(Exception ex){}
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: Как-то не так задал вопрос? За что минусы?)

Comment: Потому что пишите как курица лапой. Очень трудно разобрать.

Comment: А в браузер данные очевидно должны отправляться по os (= s.getOutputStream) Что-то не заметно что бы Вы пытались туда что-то записать

Comment: Понял, поменяю стиль писания) По теме: если так делаю, страничка просто скачивается.

Comment: Что пишите в os, то и скачивается. Ничего не пишите - ничего и не скачивается. Настоящий прокси сделать не просто. Надо разобрать запрос браузера, чтобы стало ясно куда он хочет подключиться. Подключиться туда новым клиентским сокетом. И ответ сервера со входа этого сокета копировать в os. У Вас же ничего похожего и близко не видно.